# how to display all the records on different pages according to the key in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table Sales in SQL Server 2008:

```
NIM   NAME       QTY         SALES
----- ---------- ----------- -----------
U001  RUDI       12          12000
U001  RUDI       15          16000
U001  RUDI       20          30000
U001  RUDI       6           6000
U002  MARK       10          11000
U002  MARK       12          13000
U002  MARK       19          20000
U003  JOKO       5           5000
U003  JOKO       4           4000
U003  JOKO       9           9000
```

I will create a report using Crystal Report with design like this:

```
NIM  : <nim>
NAME : <NAME>
------------
QTY    SALES
------------
<QTY> <SALES>
```

When I try to preview, then all record QTY and SALES show in one page. But I want to show them in other page according NIM and NAME as KEY.
For example:
Page 1

```
NIM  : U001
NAME : RUDI
-------------
QTY Sales
-------------
12      12000
15      16000
20      30000
6       6000
```

Page 2

```
NIM  : U002
NAME : MARK
-------------
QTY Sales
-------------
10      11000
12      13000
19      20000
```

Can you help me, how to show report like that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **Group** of NIM and place NIM and Name in Group Header. Check ON the **New Page After** property of the Group Footer in **Section Expert**.

Try and get back with results.

Comment: I was try, and then success. thanks for help.

Comment: Happy to listen your problem got resolved.

Comment: But in this case every report will generate an empty page at the end of the report. Since you gave new page after the Group Footer. You can avoid that using formula in New Page After.